# Wait time between each action

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hello I am new to python and I am trying to create an automation bot (I am very new to python) that logs into instagram and likes a certain number of posts but I am trying to figure out how to add a delay from when it enters the username information and password but I am not sure how to go about that, Also I would appreciate any feedback/recommendations thank you. Here is the code I have so far

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    def site_login():
      browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/')
      browser.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys(‘username’)
      browser.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys(“password”)
      browser.find_element_by_name("Log In").click() #not sure if this works
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time module should help you

```
import time

time.sleep(seconds) #Enter the time in seconds here
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to wait for a specified period then you can use `time.sleep(timeInSeconds)` which need `import time`.

```
import time

time.sleep(number_of_seconds)
```

But, however I would like to use the explicit wait. Unlike hard timeout, this will wait until the condition is met and continue the script.

```
# needed the imports
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

# wait for the element and click (using xpath locator)
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "xpath_goes_here"))).click()
# wait for the element and enter value (using css locator)
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "css_locator_goes_here")))).send_keys("enter input")
# store the element and then perform action
loginButton = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "css_locator_goes_here"))))
loginButton.click()
```

you can use either CSS or xpath location strategy.

You can also use implicit wait at the driver level by adding below line of code.

```
browser.implicitly_wait(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `time.sleep(seconds)` , I would recommend to use Explicit wait as the previous comment. Since due to environment changes time can be vary. So its better to use Explicit wait. Using `time.sleep(seconds)` will sleeps the current thread. It's a bad practice.

Thanks